# css: display:inline-block and span with position:relative to build multi-column dropdown

Tags: html, css

I try to created multicolumn menu [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergey80/uz0do787/23/) (**updated link** is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/32/)):

I made used of `display: inline-block` strategy to make (horizontal) rows. And seems it works.
But it stops work when I wrapped it into the `span` which comes with `position:relative`.

```
<section>
    <button>123</button>
    <button>123</button>

    <span class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">*</a>    <!-- this is a link that should be inline with buttons -->

            <div class="menu">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <li>11111111111111111111111111</li>
                        <li>1111111111111</li>
                        <li>111</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <li>2222222222</li>
                        <li>222222222222222222222</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <li>33</li>
                        <li>33</li>
                        <li>33</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
</span>
</section>
```

The href link in the `span` represents a button or link where I would click to make menu appeared. 
I have to have position relative in the span to make menu appears on right place, relatively to it.
(all buttons and link should be on the same horizontal line)

Question: how to make it working?

*It works though if I change `span` to `div` and make fixed size for it like `width:600px` (and this width have be more or less of the menu width to make it work like expected, which is weird), but/so I want it to be `span` (with no specific/hard-coded width).*

**UPDATE**:

I've updated my example to show how it works with span as block and buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/32/

**Just put a little more detail that was not shown on previous demo, to show what I want.
I want all buttons and the href link be on the same line, but making span "display:block" breaks that order.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess If fixed it by switching to `display:table` then I can stay with `span` not trying to make it block and it does not jump then to the next line:

Before:
http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/32/

After

http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/34/

But in any case, I think there is a room for re-factoring - the menu should be independent to show itself by js by x,y depending on the span/link location so that the DOM not to be so dependable on each other and not to be so fragile.

And I just do not understand, why when I apply "display:table" (on that solution/answer I proposed) span stays on place with buttons, but with "display:inline-block" the span breaks the menu layout. What makes display:table works like expected comparing to inline-block solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display:block` to `span`

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6xvvweo/)

See why you need to add `display:block`

> The HTML `<span>` element is a generic inline container for phrasing
>   content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used
>   to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id
>   attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It
>   should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate.
>   `<span>` is very much like a  element, but `<div>` is a block-level
>   element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element.

Source:**[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)**

Comment: I've updated my demo to show that it does not work for my case I described: http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/32/  Just put a little more detail that was not shown on previous demo, to show what I want.
I want all buttons and link be on the same line.. and "block" breaks it.

Comment: I am currently using the app so I can't check this right now. In a bit I will see your fiddle.

Comment: Close to that. I just dont understand why when I apply "display:table" (on that solution/answer I proposed) span stays on place with buttons, but with "display:inline-block" the span breaks the menu layout. What makes display:table works like expected comparing to inline-block solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68849/discussion-between-dippas-and-ses).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz0do787/36/)

```
.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
   position:absolute;
   top: -15px;
   left: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: yes, but in your case you moved it upper artificially by magic -15px to be in-line with buttons and the menu itself shifted.

Comment: Ok. What if you position the `section` relative and position everything in it absolute so you have total control over every element in your `section`.

Answer (score 0):

Span - this is an inline element. You can't wrap block with inline element. To make it work with span, add "display: block;" property to the  .dropdown

Like:

```
.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}
```